# How to get all the email addresses that belongs to the sender's group, in outlook 2010, using powershell scripts

Tags: email, powershell, scripting, outlook

I would like to get all the email addresses that belongs to the sender's group, in outlook 2010 professional, using PowerShell.

For example, person A sends me an e-mail, and A belongs to group X. So I would like to use PowerShell to get all the email addresses that belongs to group X.

I was reading outlook Api documentations but found nothing related to that. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Ruijie

Comment: What are "groups" in this regard? Are these groups in Outlook contact list, or other distribution lists? What to do if A belongs to more than one group?

Comment: Could you give us some screen shots or a more specific example, I don't really understand what you're trying to do.  Are you talking about Distribution Groups / Contact lists?  For instance, I send an email to a list I have called 'Everyone Accounting'.  You get a copy of that e-mail.  You want to know who is in Everyone Accounting?

Comment: I am new here and I don't have enough reputation to post an image.  What I want is this: In my company, we have different teams. And they are grouped in this way in outlook. I can sent an e-mail to this team so everyone in this team will get an copy of this e-mail.                        Now what I want is when someone sends me an email, I want to know who else is in his team and their email addresses. I can directly see this when I open outlook, but I am wondering how to get it using powershell. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "Member of" tab in the Exchange user properties dialog? Retrieve AddressEntry object from MailItem.Sender, then use AddressEntry.GetExchnageUser().GetMemberOfList function (be prepared to handle null and/or errors). Loop through all items in the returned AddressEntries list.

Comment: This might be better to do via AD tools, not Outlook-only. But if OP meant contact list (local mailbox) groups, there is another API via enumerating items of type `DistListItem` and checking if any contains the sender.